# Why is my time data format not matching when using datetime in python?

Tags: python

I am importing a large number of dates in the form DD/MM/YYYY from a csv file into python and want to group them by just MM-YYYY. One method I have tried is the following:

```
str=date.iloc[2]
```

which results in str=7/18/2019. But what I want to do is convert it to Jul 2019 to make groupings by month and year. I have tried doing this

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("str","%m/%d/%Y").strptime("%b %Y")
```

and get the following error "time data 'str' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'. I have also tried str.replace("/","-") but that did not help either but when I manually type in the date

`datetime.datetime.strptime("7/18/2019","%m/%d/%Y").strptime("%b %Y")`

it works exactly as I'd like it to. This is an easy fix but my date dataframe contains hundreds of dates and would ultimately like to run it in a loop to automate it. I cannot seem to find why format does not match. I've done research but no one seems to be having the same issue. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("str","%m/%d/%Y").strptime("%b %Y")
```

Is to parse literally the string of "str" into the date. Instead, you should do

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str,"%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%b %Y")
```

Comment: when I try that I get the error "strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)" . after making that change, I learned that the error is regarding the second .strptime

Comment: edited my answer as I did not realize the second part should be strftime. strptime is for parsing datetime from text, and strftime is to format the datetime into a string with desired format.

Comment: That helps, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime's `strftime()`:

```
import datetime

a = '07/22/1990'

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y")
dd = d.strftime("%m/%Y")

print('d: ', d)
print('dd: ', dd)


# or in one line
ddd = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%m/%Y")
print('ddd: ', ddd)
```

The output:

```
$ python p.py
d:  1990-07-22 00:00:00
dd:  07/1990
ddd:  07/1990
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("str","%m/%d/%Y").strptime("%b %Y")
```

`"str"` is a string literal. You want the variable `str`

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(str,"%m/%d/%Y").strptime("%b %Y")
```

Comment: when I try that I get the error "strptime() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"